# How to get 12am 7 days ago?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code  `var daysAgo7 = Date.now() - (7*86400*1000);`

How can I convert that code to get 12am 7 days ago? I don't want to get 7 days ago. I want to get 12am 7 days ago. How do I do that?

Comment: Have you tried [setHours](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours)?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: `const d = new Date(); d.setDate(d.getDate()-7); d.setHours(12,0,0,0);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go back seven days, then just use [`Date#setHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) to adjust the time portion:

```js
var date = new Date("2020-12-02T16:53:12.215"); //assume a stable time
//go seven days back
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 7);
//set the time to 12:00:00.000
date.setHours(12, 0, 0 , 0);

console.log(date.toString());        //human-readable
console.log(date.getTime());         //Unix timeastamp in milliseconds
console.log(date.getTime() / 1000);  //regula Unix timeastamp in seconds
```

Comment: `date.setHours(12,0,0,0);`

Comment: @mplungjan ...I guess I should read the very documentation I was linking to. Thanks! Let me edit this.

Comment: Why. It is already answered in the comments - question is not worth answering - surely some dupe

Comment: @mplungjan I cannot find a good dupe target. There is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944379/get-date-object-with-specific-time) but I think it's distinct enough for this question here to have merit. I'm still searching for a good dupe but most things I find are simply more complex - how to get a time in a specific timezone, how to get an interval length, etc.

Comment: @mplungjan Questions really shouldn't be answered in the comments. It makes it harder for other visitors to find information.

Comment: @iota Questions that are not worth answering should be answered in the comments to help the asker who can then delete their poor question